# How can I display a WebForm in a Modal Window

Tags: ajax, webforms, javascript

I am using [Webform (4.11)](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).  I have a 'simple' form with 2 fields that I would like to display in a modal dialog when the 'Apply' button is pressed.

So imagine I have a page with an apply button, and when the user selects this button, I need to know if they are an existing client (they are not logged in), and some other 'meta data' (second field).

Bottom line - I would just like to display the webform that has these questions, in a modal dialog.

I know I can create a custom module, to create a custom form, and use CTools to show the form in a modal window, but then I lose all the functionality that comes with the Webform module.

Answer (score 1):

Use [modal form](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module to load into modal window. Create link using modules custom method after check user is loggedin.

```
$links[] = ctools_modal_text_button(t('webform'), 'modal_forms/nojs/webform-path', t('Webform via modal'),  'ctools-modal-modal-popup-small');
```